# How can I install packages in knitr?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Till now, I was using this chunk of code to load R packages and write .R files. But I am trying to use knitr

```
rm (list=ls(all=TRUE))
kpacks <- c('ggplot2','install_github','devtools','mapdata')
new.packs <- kpacks[!(kpacks %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packs)) install.packages(new.packs)
lapply(kpacks, require, character.only=T)
remove(kpacks, new.packs)
options(max.print=5.5E5)
```

But now, when I put this chunk of code in a Knitr document, I get this error:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror calls:......
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The narrow answer to your question is that you should set your `repos` option:

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="<something sensible near you>"))
```

You're hitting the problem because R's default behaviour when the repository option is initially unset is to query the user -- and it can't do that when you're running code non-interactively.

More broadly, I would question whether you want to include this sort of thing in your R code; under some circumstances it can be problematic.

- what if the user doesn't have a network connection?
- what if they are geographically very far from you so that your default repository setting doesn't make sense?
- what if they don't feel like downloading and installing a (possibly large) package?

My preferred practice is to specify in the instructions for running the code that users should have packages X, Y, Z installed (and giving them example code to install them, in case they're inexperienced with R).

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I do it so that users don't have to put their brains into loading packages. Internet isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid installing the packages is to do something like

```
if(!require(package.name))
  stop("you need to install package.name")
```

In your code chunk. Depending on your knitr document settings, this will generate the message in the document, in the console, or prevent the document from being knitted.

Comment: this is already handled in the OP's code by checking the list of packages to install against `installed.packages()` ...

Comment: @Ben, that's true but my suggestion is more about communicating with the user rather than installing the packages. Using a series of `if(!require())` statements helps address the various points you listed when asking whether it is a good idea to have a `knitr` document try to force install R packages, while still keeping it simple for the user.