# I keep getting a knit error with my markdown file in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, codemirror, cran

I am receiving this error when trying to knit my R markdown sheet

Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Are you using `install.packages` in the "notebook"? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969024/install-packages-fails-in-knitr-document-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674311/how-can-i-install-packages-in-knitr). I suggest installing outside the notebook and using `eval=FALSE` in the install code chunk.

Comment: Hi NelsonGon.. I have read the links you gave me but I don't really understand them. I am very new to the language. I have the packages in my rmd with eval=FALSE present but when I do this I get a notification saying it cannot find my function. I have installed them in my console but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the exact code, it is difficult to assess the problem. However, as @NelsonGon writes, this is usually the error from running an installation (`install.packages()` inside a chunk.

Instead, the library should be installed beforehand and loaded with `library(example`) inside a chunk to make it available for the markdown environment.

Comment: My current code looks like this  ```{r Library, eval=FALSE}

install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)

register_google(key = "xxx")

```